# Absorption probability in 1D RW with asymmetric step sizes, $ x<0 $

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, linear-algebra, random-walk

What is the probability of absorption at $ 0 $, as a function of position $ x $, for a 1D random walk (on $ \mathbb{Z} $) with asymmetric step sizes?

For example, suppose that you can take two steps to the right with probability $ p $, or one step to the left with probability $ q=1-p $. I calculated the probabilities for $ x>0 $ via difference equations*, but I'm stuck for the case $ x<0 $. Obviously it matters whether $ x $ is even or odd; in the case that $ p=1 $ the probabilities should bounce between $ 0 $ (if $ x $ odd) and $ 1 $ (if $ x $ even).

*For $ x>0 $, I found $ P(x)=\left(\frac{-p+\sqrt{4p-3p^{2}}}{2p}\right)^{x} $.